# Missing column names and case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Can you suggest a workaround for this error I'm triggering? (in R 3.6.2)

Using a `case_when` in a `mutate`, trying to test if a column is present, and only then use its value:

```
library(tidyverse)
aCaseFn <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    mutate(UP =
             case_when("plays" %in% names(df) ~ toupper(plays),
                       "band" %in% names(df) ~ toupper(band),
                       TRUE ~ NA_character_))
}
```

What I'm expecting is

```
R > aCaseFn(band_instruments)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  plays  UP    
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 John  guitar GUITAR
2 Paul  bass   BASS  
3 Keith guitar GUITAR
```

but instead I get this error error

```
R > aCaseFn(band_instruments)
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `UP`.
x object 'band' not found
ℹ Input `UP` is `case_when(...)`.
```

It appears that the `toupper(band)` is getting evaluated, even tho (I'd think) it shouldn't ever be reached with this argument - both because the 1st branch (`"plays" %in% names(df)`)  is TRUE and because the 2nd branch's conditional (`"band" %in% names(df)`) is FALSE.

So what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Easier option is `any_of` - create two formal arguments - one for inputting the dataset and second for the column names to convert to uppercase as string (nms)., loop `across` `any_of` the columns in 'nms' i.e. if it will only loop over the columns that exist in the data.frame and leave out the ones that are not present from the vector, convert to uppercase and change the column names with `.names`.

```
aCaseFn <- function(df, nms) 
{

df %>%
    mutate(across(any_of(nms), toupper, .names = "UP_{.col}"))
}
```

-testing

```
str1 <- c("plays", "band")
> aCaseFn(band_instruments, str1)
   name  plays UP_plays
1  John guitar   GUITAR
2  Paul   bass     BASS
3 Keith guitar   GUITAR
```

NOTE: `case_when/if_else/ifelse` requires all the arguments to be of same length i.e. `"plays" %in% names(df)` returns a single TRUE/FALSE output where as `toupper(plays)` `length` will be the `nrow(df)`.  Here `if/else` would be more useful..

#### data

```
band_instruments <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Paul", 
"Keith"), plays = c("guitar", 
"bass", "guitar")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm looking for an answer within `case_when`.

Comment: @DavidT `case_when` is not useful for your case i.e. it checks for `length` to be same in all arguments

Comment: @DavidT what I meant in my post is that you can use `exists` with `if/else if` i.e. `band_instruments %>% mutate(UP = if(exists('plays')) toupper(plays) else if(exists('bands')) toupper(bands) else NA)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the set of columns is fixed for all rows, you don't have to check it row-wise with `case_when`.  I think you might want to determine the name of the target column first, and then use it in `mutate`:

```r
target_columns <- c('plays', 'band')
col_n <- which(target_columns %in% colnames(df))
up_column <- target_columns[if (length(col_n) > 0) min(col_n) else col_n]
df %>% 
    mutate(
        UP = if (length(up_column) > 0) {
            toupper(.data[[up_column]])
        } else {
            NA_character_
        }
    )
```